# Files uploaded using FileZilla with SFTP are missing permissions

Tags: file-permissions, sftp, chroot, ftp

I am using chroot in sftp. And it works perfectly, but files uploaded with FileZilla are stored without any permissions (basically 000).

```
---------- 1 cwsftp sftp 4364328 Jan 19 16:02 hygq8KAZ3seC.128.mp3
```

This is my setup in the `sshd_config`:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match Group sftpusers
        ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
```

I already tried adding `-u 0002` and such things, without effect.

Comment: What client are you using. Pretty sure this is a problem from that.

Comment: I am using Filezilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in FileZilla 3.10.0-beta3 through 3.10.0.1.

https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=34953

Either upgrade to 3.10.0.2 or later. Or use another SFTP client.

Comment: 3.10.0.2 does NOT fix the problem when connected via public key!

Comment: @codesight OK. Does that mean, it works when corrected using password? Or is it irrelevant note? Did you try any other SFTP client? WinSCP?